# AMAZON.FIVE_DIGIT_NUMBER does not exist to capture zipcode in Amazon Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Alexa certification feedback says to use slot type "AMAZON.FIVE_DIGIT_NUMBER" for zipcodes. That would make sense, but it doesn't actually exist!

When I include this slot type, I am unable to save the intent json It gives the error: *"Unknown slot type 'AMAZON.FIVE_DIGIT_NUMBER' for slot 'POSTCODE'"*.

I can replace with AMAZON.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER and it works great and captures all 5 digits nicely. However, this issue was mentioned as a reason for failed certification.

I can replace with AMAZON.NUMBER which kinda works (as per suggestion in certification), but often only captures the first 4 digits, ironically not as well as AMAZON.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER which almost always captures all 5.

I want to pass certification but the AMAZON.NUMBER seems to give inferior results.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you got back info from the Alexa certification people.  There is no AMAZON.FIVE_DIGIT_NUMBER built-in slot, even in the big new batch of built-in slots that they added recently.

There is AMAZON.PostalAddress and various built-ins for cities, but neither of those really fit the bill, so you are stuck with AMAZON.NUMBER.