# How to get the time zone

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to get the time for my echo skill. I got the time, but it is in the wrong time zone. how do I make it to where the time adjusts to the time zone?

Here is my code:

```
var d = new Date(); 
var dateHour = d.getHours();
var dateMinutes = d.getMinutes();

var nonTime = dateHour + ":" + dateMinutes;
var dateTime = nonTime

var speechOutput = "This is a test " + today + ' ' + dateTime ;
this.emit(':tellWithCard', speechOutput, today); },
```

The time that I posted this is 10:16, here is what my log displays:

```
   "outputSpeech": {
  "type": "SSML",
  "ssml": "<speak> This is a test September 5, 2017 3:16 </speak>"
```

Comment: According to this, it's not available: [Alexa skills custom slot for date times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39737139/174777)

Comment: Also, please note that Lambda (and EC2) use UTC as the timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Momentjs is your friend. You can pass in your time zone and get the current time in that zone.

https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

All scripts run in UTC timezone. You need to specify the timezone of the user.